# How can I change an attribute in a parent node?

Tags: xml, xslt, parent-node

This is the XML block:

```
<Object type="proto">
    <Name value="test1"/>
    <Enabled value="1"/>
    <System value="active"/>
    <Time value="10"/>
</Object>
<Object type="proto">
    <Name value="test2"/>
    <Enabled value="1"/>
    <System value="active"/>
    <Time value="20"/>
</Object>
```

How do I change the value of 'Time' only for 'test1' during a copy?

Comment: Show how the expected output looks like, and what you have so far in term of XSL codes

Comment: I already have the base identity copy, which will copy the entire block with its nodes and attributes. But I want to change the value of Time for test1, say fro 10 to 30. I need to understand how to specify that the change has to affect only the test1 block.

Comment: Next time please post XSL codes you already have, so that people can base their answer on that XSL. This way, to mention some of many benefits, hopefully the answer will be easier to understand for you, and easier to write for the helper. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one possible way :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Object[Name/@value='test1']/Time">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">30</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Brief explanation regarding `xsl:template`s being used :

- `<xsl:template match="@* | node()">...` : Identity template; copies nodes and attributes to the output XML, unchanged.
- `<xsl:template match="Object[Name/@value='test1']/Time">...` : Overrides identity template for `<Time>` element, that is direct child of `<Object>` having child `Name/@value` equals `test1`. This template copies the matched `<Time>` element and change the attribute `value` to `30`.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I didn't know you could specify 'Object[Name/@value='test1']/' in match